# Changing a variable in a def function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Okay, weird question. So I'm making a text adventure game for a school project, and I'm making a shop system. It's supposed to only allow you to buy one of each item, with the exception of potions.

```
schoice = str(input("> "))
def shopresults(item, itemvar, price):
  if schoice == str(item):
    if itemvar == 0 and gold >= price:
      print("Here ya go! One " + str(item) + " coming  right up!")
      # itemvar = 1 this should change the variable determining the status of the item, e.g. swordfire1 or swordfire2  
      gold == gold - price
      if item == "fire sword" or itemvar == "water sword" or itemvar == "thunder sword":
         freesword = 0
         elif itemvar == 1 and (item != potion1 or item != potion2 or item != potion3):
            print("You already have that, kiddo!")
         elif gold < price:
            print("You're a little short on gold there, bud...")
shopresults("fire sword", swordfire1, (100 - (100 * freesword)))
shopresults("flame sword", swordfire2, 500)
```

How do I change the variable that is called before you get into the shopresults program, in this case swordfire1, instead of the itemvar itself? swordfire1 determines if you have the 1st fire sword, and there's variables like this for every weapon. Ignore the freesword variable, you basically get one free sword in the game, and that's not the problem as far as I know. I know this is confusing, but please help if you can.

Comment: is this all your code? what is swordfire1, and swordfire2?

Comment: @ppwater Oh no, there's more, I just trimmed it down to save on space. swordfire1 determines whether or not you own the 1st level of fire sword, and swordfire2 determines the 2nd level. They should be defined earlier in the code.

Comment: you can just enter all your code

Comment: It's well over 200 lines of code, and most of it doesn't apply to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I'm wondering what is the value of `swordfire1` and `swordfire2`- they look like integers? My thinking is you should think about creating weapon objects and maintaining a registry of weapons. Based on the status, call your registry and return your weapon object to that variable. When I say registry you can use a simple dict or you can design a factory like pattern.

Comment: Yeah, they're integers, but they only have a 0 or a 1. Thanks for your answer, but I don't think I can use that since we haven't learned that in class.

Comment: Well if you only have 0 or 1, why not just swap the variable to opposite integer i.e if 0 itemvar = 1 if 1 itemvar = 0? @pythonnoob02

Comment: The problem with changing itemvar is that it doesn't modify the original variable, i.e. swordfire1. I'm trying to modify it, but I'm not sure how to in a more general sense.

Comment: lets say we execute  `shopresults("fire sword", swordfire1, (100 - (100 * freesword)))` and you want swordfire1 to say the same. when you run `shopresults("flame sword", swordfire2, 500)` are you expecting swordfire2 to actually contain the value of swordfire1?

Comment: No, it should contain the value of `swordfire2`. Here, let me break it down in a brute force way: `if item == "fire sword": swordfire1 = 1 elif item == "flame sword": swordfire2 = 1` etc.

Comment: well first things first swordfire1 isn't in scope of the function.. all you can work with is itemvar since that represents swordfire1 when we enter the function.  if you want to more flexbility, you would want to write a class and initialize  swordfire1 and swordfire2 that you can use self key. Also, the logic you provided above always is 1 so you dont even need to check what `item` equals.

Comment: Maybe make shopresults return itemvar and you can pass the return value into the following function

Answer (score 0):

Variable assignment is done with `=` not  `==`. And you need combine the conditions with parentheses:

```
schoice = str(input("> "))
def shopresults(item, itemvar, price):
  if schoice == str(item):
    if (itemvar == 0) and (gold >= price):
      print("Here ya go! One " + str(item) + " coming  right up!")
      # itemvar = 1 this should change the variable determining the status of the item, e.g. swordfire1 or swordfire2  
      gold = gold - price
      if (item == "fire sword") or (itemvar == "water sword") or (itemvar == "thunder sword"):
         freesword = 0
         elif (itemvar == 1) and (item != potion1) or (item != potion2) or (item != potion3):
            print("You already have that, kiddo!")
         elif gold < price:
            print("You're a little short on gold there, bud...")

shopresults("fire sword", swordfire1, (100 - (100 * freesword)))
shopresults("flame sword", swordfire2, 500)
```

Comment: If they help you to understand it then that's fine, but I don't think you need the parentheses.

Comment: I guess it looks better, but that doesn't answer my question.